# What if an if and else statement are true?

Tags: if-statement, artificial-intelligence

Hello I'm trying to code a tic-tac-toe game and wanted to create an AI that plays randomly, except when the human player is about to win. However, I've run into a small issue here. Suppose the index(?) of the 3x3 grid goes like this:

123

456

789

If a and b are filled by the opponent's shape, then I want to check if:

a) the two numbers are in a row/column/diagonal

then,

b) the winning position (that the AI will block) is empty or filled already

```
def preventOwin(start): #win conditions
#rows
  if start[1] == start[2] == 'O':
    a = 3
    if checkfree(a) == True:
      print(start.update({a:'X'}))
      return True
  elif start[1] == start[3] == 'O':
    a = 2
    if checkfree(a) == True:
      print(start.update({a:'X'}))
      return True
```

etc.

So I want the AI to check if there are two O's in a row (eg in position 1 and 2), and see if the third position is filled already. If no, then I just continue with my game by updating the 3rd position's dictionary value to O. If *yes*, then there's a problem because then I want to check the rest of the elif statements and see if they're true or not.

eg:
board is:

-|x|o

-|o|-

x|o|-

the human plays:

o|x|o

-|o|-

x|o|-

The AI sees 1 and 3 are O's, but 2 is filled. I want to check the rest of the conditions after this because, in this case, 1 and 5 are also O's and 9 is empty.

Is this question contradictory to the nature of if-else statements?

Comment: think how your program will behave if you replace `elif` with simple `if`?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked immediately :)